# List set in onActivityResult with data not sticking

Tags: java, android, onactivityresult

I need to set a List variable using data returned from onActivityResult. Then use that list to do things when a button is pressed.

If I put a Log.d of the list right after setting it inside onActivityResult, it correctly shows the list. But if I put a second Log.d of the list inside onResume or when the button is pressed, the second log shows the list as null.

Not full code, just relevant parts.

```
public class ImageSelectActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static List<String> path;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_select);
    Button btnSelectImages = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelect);
    btnSelectImages.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            MultiImageSelector selector = MultiImageSelector.create(ImageSelectActivity.this);
            selector.count(12);
            selector.showCamera(true);
            selector.start(ImageSelectActivity.this, REQUEST_IMAGE);
        }
    });

    Button btnImagesLog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnImages);
    btnImagesLog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("path",""+path); //path returns null even AFTER clicking the select button and selecting images.
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            // list of image paths
            List<String> path = data.getStringArrayListExtra(MultiImageSelectorActivity.EXTRA_RESULT);
            Log.d("images",""+path); //correctly displays path of all selected images.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: go ahead and add code

Comment: There is no point in *explaining* what you *assume* your code is doing. Obviously your code is **not** doing what you expect it to do; and we can only help with code problems ... if there is code to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is **shadowing**:

You declare a completely **new** list object in that method:

```
// list of image paths
List<String> path = data.getStringArrayListExtra(MultiImageSelectorActivity.EXTRA_RESULT);
```

That is a local variable! Thus you are not assigning a value to ImageSelectActivity.path, but to that local variable. And ImageSelectActivity.path just keeps its **old** value.

So, the answer is simply: turn that lines into

```
// list of image paths
path = data.getStringArrayListExtra(MultiImageSelectorActivity.EXTRA_RESULT);
```

and you should be good. Well, except for the thing that using **static** variables is often not a good idea.

Beyond that: this is **really** basic stuff. If you don't know about such things, I recommend you to **first** study education material on those Java basics before further engaging with Android. For example: work your way through the Oracle [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/); at least the basic ones!

Comment: My brain was completely ignore that List<String>. Knew it was going to be something super simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new reference variable and assigning list to it

```
List<String> path = data.getStringArrayListExtra(MultiImageSelectorActivity.EXTRA_RESULT); 
// ^^^^^ new local variable
```

so you need to use the already defined variable so just do it like this

```
 public static List<String> path;
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            // list of image paths
            path = data.getStringArrayListExtra(MultiImageSelectorActivity.EXTRA_RESULT);
           //^^^^ don't create a local variable , 
           //just refer the one already defined in class 
            Log.d("images",""+path);
        }
    }
}
```